# Is the following true about eigenspaces?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a (EDIT: symmetric) matrix $A$. I find all of its eigenvalues and vectors (let's assume all values are distinct) such that $A = U \Sigma U^{\top}$ and everything is real.

Is it true that the columns of $U$ are orthogonal under the dot product $x \cdot y = x^{\top} A A^{\top} y$ where $x$ and $y$ are the columns of $U$?

(proof: if $x$ is a column of $U$ then $Ax = \lambda x$ for some scalar, therefore the dot product, whether it is 0 or not, is just the product of two scalars by the inner product of $x$ and $y$, and the columns of $U$ are orthogonal because they are eigenvectors of distinct eigenvalues.)

Comment: Your initial equation there, namely that $A = U \Sigma U^{\top}$ is not guaranteed by your written hypothesis. In general, a real matrix with distinct real eigenvalues only guarantees that $A = U \Sigma U^{-1}$, where $\Sigma$ is diagonal. Your equation is equivalent to assuming that the matrix is symmetric, which is much stronger, and the conclusion you have is well known in that context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eigenvectors corresponding to distinct eigenvalues are *linearly independent*, but they are not necessarily *orthogonal*.

In the case of a symmetric matrix, regardless of repeated eigenvalues, the eigenvectors can *always* be chosen to be orthogonal with the Gram-Schmidt process if necessary, and can be chosen to be orthonormal, in fact.

A symmetric matrix $A$ can be decomposed as $QDQ^T$, the product of an orthogonal matrix (columns are orthonormal), a diagonal matrix containing the eigenvalues of $A$, and the inverse of $Q$, which is the transpose for orthogonal matrices.

Comment: thanks @AOrtiz. is it possible to find an orthogonal basis for the eigenvectors, such that each element in the basis is an eigenvector? I am guessing no.

Comment: In the case of a symmetric matrix yes, in general, no.

Comment: @linearAlgebra in general, no. However, for symmetric matrices, the answer is affirmative. This is a consequence of the spectral theorem.

Comment: oh, I forgot to mention, my matrix $A$ is actually symmetric, so I think in this case they are orthogonal! that was implied by my decomposition $A = U \Sigma U^{\top}$ instead of $U^{-1}$.

Comment: @linearAlebra then you have your answer, yes. The eigenvectors of $A
$ are orthogonal.

Comment: thank you. what if I have an eigenvector decomposition where one of the eigenvalues has multiplicity larger than 1? I guess I can orthogonalize each eigenspace separately.

Comment: @linearAlgebra algebraic multiplicity has no bearing on the matter. The eigenvectors can always be found to be orthogonal.

Comment: @AOrtiz note that with repeated eigenvalues, it is *possible* to find a basis of eigenvectors that are not mutually orthogonal (e.g. with $A=I$). In order to make an orthonormal basis (from an arbitrary eigenbasis), one must generally apply Gram Schmidt for each eigenspace.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom yes thank you for that reminder!